# Twitchlib PubSub cant see events

Tags: c#, twitch, twitch-api

Im trying to listen to predictions and channel point rewards. But PubSub is completely silent and I can't figure out why.

```
using TwitchLib.PubSub;
using TwitchLib.PubSub.Events;

namespace PubSub_app
{
    class PubSub
    {
        TwitchPubSub client;
        public PubSub()
        {
            client = new TwitchPubSub();
            client.OnPubSubServiceConnected += Pubsub_OnPubSubServiceConnected;
            client.OnChannelPointsRewardRedeemed += Pubsub_OnChannelPointsRewardRedeemed;
            client.OnPrediction += Pubsub_OnPrediction;  
        
            client.Connect();
        }

        private void Pubsub_OnPubSubServiceConnected(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            client.ListenToChannelPoints("62651386");
            client.ListenToPredictions("62651386");
            Console.WriteLine("PubSub Connected");
        }            
        
        private void Pubsub_OnPrediction(object sender, OnPredictionArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Prediction");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Title);
        } 

        private void Pubsub_OnChannelPointsRewardRedeemed(object sender, OnChannelPointsRewardRedeemedArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Points redeemed");
            Console.WriteLine(e.RewardRedeemed);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing that console displays that its connected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `client.SendTopics(accessToken);` line in `Pubsub_OnPubSubServiceConnected`.